# ActiveAdmin Cross Reference Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

I have two different models. One called 'Books' and one called 'Author'. In ActiveAdmin, when creating a new 'book' under 'Books', how can I have a dropdown in the form with a list of Authors from the 'Author' model?

I have been searching for a hint all day and haven't managed to come up with anything yet.. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

**alexandrine_greenfelder**'s answer is a proper solution, but when it comes to bigger amounts of data, this kind of loading entries for selection takes a lot of time.

[`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) is much faster in this context:

```
f.input :author, as: :select, collection: -> { Author.pluck(:full_name, :id) }
```

Also notу how I use lambda to seed a collection:

```
-> { Author.pluck(:full_name, :id) }
```

This way the data will be loaded from database once selection dropdown is clicked, not when the model is initialized (which prevent situations, when new `Author` instance is added to db, but not present in dropdown yet).

Comment: Hi @Andrey i use with lambda but its not work i get an error like "undefined method `map' for #<Proc:0x00007f3ae403d240>" but i write f.input :author, as: :select, collection: Author.pluck(:full_name, :id) it's working. here is how exactly the use of the lambda

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
f.input :author, as: :select, collection: Author.all.map { |a| [a.full_name, b.id] }
```

in `form` section.